# Three.js: OrbitControls zoom minDistance issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using `OrbitControl` for navigation. In my scene, I have two planes which are defining a 100x100x100 cube in which I load different data.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4p8h/1/

My problem is, that I can't zoom in my cube! I think it has something to do with `minDistance`, so I experimented with it like

```
controls.minDistance = -Infinity
```

but it has no effect. I found out that every number under zero has no effect.

I don't want to limit the zoomIn, the user should be able to zoom to every point in my cube. How can I fix this limitation?

Comment: Well, you are misunderstanding camera zoom and movement. I think what you are looking for is some kind of movement when using the scroll wheel to move the camera in the direction it is facing. The orbit controls zoom gets slower and the increments smaller the more you zoom in, thus  you cannot move any further.

Answer (score 4):

You set `controls.target` in the wrong place -- in front of your cube. You need to set it to the center of your cube.

```
 controls.target.set( 50, 50, -50 );
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4p8h/2/

three.js r.62

Comment: I'm confirming this works too. If you have a Raycaster and set the controls.target.set to be the X, Y, and Z of the raycasted object, you can zoom in as far as you'd like into the object. Works great.